# JPA: How to persist column with SHA1 encryption  ?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm fairly new to JPA (and JPQL by extension). Hopefully, someone will be able to enlighten me with this problem.

The query I'm trying to execute ...

```
String query = "select u from user u where u.email = '" + userEmail + "' and u.password = sha1('"+ userPassword + "')";
List resultList = emf.createEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

And I'm getting the follwowing exception ...

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select u from Utilisateur u where u.email = 'myuser' and u.mot_Passe = sha1('mypassword')], line 1, column 73: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unexpectedToken(JPQLException.java:372)
...
```

Obviously, I'm missing something here, should I escape the character somehow? specify it in another way? I'll appreciate very much any help on this.

Comment: As S.P.F says, you need to compute SHA1 in Java code and then set it as password parameter to the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that JPA doesn't have a sha1 function. So you have two options:

1. You can implementa a sha1 function on you Java code and use them before load the parameters in the query.

   ```
   String query = "select u from user u where u.email = :userEmail" +
      " and u.password = :userPassword";
   Query jpqlQuery = em.createQuery(query)
       .setParameter("userEmail", userEmail)
       .setParameter("userPassword",sha1(userPassword));
   ```
2. If your database has the sha1 function you can write a native query. Check this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

   ```
   List<Customer> customers = (List<Customer>)em.createNativeQuery
           ("SELECT * FROM customers", jpqlexample.entities.Customer.class)
                         .getResultList(); 
   Iterator i = customers.iterator();
   Customer cust;
   while (i.hasNext()) {
       cust = (Customer) i.next();
       //do something
   }
   ```

Comment: It looks like JPA doesn't support cryptographic hash functions. Thanks for the suggestion of these alternatives.

Comment: Implementing a sha1 function on Java made the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Set the parameters through the Query interface instead of adding them literally to the JPQL String. That way you are also protecting yourself from [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/):

```
String query =
   "select u from user u where u.email = :userEmail"
   + " and u.password = sha1(:userPassword)";
Query jpqlQuery = em.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter("userEmail", userEmail)
    .setParameter("userPassword",userPassword)
```

Comment: That will protect me against SQL Injection, I agree. However, it doesn't solve my original issue (still getting the parsing exception).

Comment: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select u from Utilisateur u where u.email = :userEmail and u.password = sha1(:userPassword)], line 1, column 76: unexpected token [(].

Comment: @WardFlores Uhm, does JPA have a sha1 function, because [I don't think so](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13046/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_functional)?

Comment: Thanks Sean, yes you're right, apparently JPA doesn't support sha1 function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In EclipseLink you can use the FUNC query word to use a database specific function.

"select u from user u where u.email = :email and u.password = FUNC('sha1', :password)"

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Support_for_Native_Database_Functions