# Automatically compute hash value for password field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish

Is there any way to tell Glassfish that the hash value for a certain data member of an entity class should be calculated and stored in the database instead of the original value?

Comment: You should hash the `Object` yourself before persisting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the getter of a field to produce its hash instead of original value, you might end up with the hash stored instead.

If your database has a hash function, other option is to issue native query using entitiy manager.

Give it a try

Comment: Sure, that's a nice idea. I am just wondering if there is any way to tell the persistence unit that the hash value should be calculated, because maybe that would make possible using the hashing capabilities of the database engine.

Comment: If your database has a hash function you can issue native query using entitiy manager. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868939/jpa-how-to-persist-column-with-sha1-encryption

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Your first suggestion works fine.